# Rails ActiveRecord Query Order by day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to sort/order my records to display them in Chart.js

I want to display meal orders from Monday to Sunday with ascending order, there are 3 different meals every day. It's kinda working if every meal if present on each day, but if one kind of meal isn't ordered, for example, the order of the days gets weird.

Here is an example where it isn't working as I intended:

[image]

So as you see (don't mind the german language :D) the starting is right Monday, ... Thursday, ... Saturday, that's fine, but the order on Friday (the green one) is another meal as on the other days and so Friday is shown after Saturday, but I want it to be shown between Thursday and Saturday.

Here are my queries for ActiveRecord:

```
    def self.weeklyVollkostOverview
        where(day: Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week).where(dish_type: 0).group(:day).order("day ASC").count
    end

    def self.weeklySchonkostOverview
        where(day: Date.today.beginning_of_week .. Date.today.end_of_week).where(dish_type: 1).group(:day).order("day ASC").count
    end

    def self.weeklyVegetarischOverview
        where(day: Date.today.beginning_of_week .. Date.today.end_of_week).where(dish_type: 2).group(:day).order("day ASC").count
    end
```

In my controller, I'm mapping the results:

```
    @weeklyVoll = OrderCard.weeklyVollkostOverview.map { |key, value| [I18n.l(key, format: "%A", locale: :'de'), value]}
    @weeklySchon = OrderCard.weeklySchonkostOverview.map { |key, value| [I18n.l(key, format: "%A", locale: :'de'), value]}
    @weeklyVegetarisch = OrderCard.weeklyVegetarischOverview.map { |key, value| [I18n.l(key, format: "%A", locale: :'de'), value]}
```

Finally, I display the results in my chart.

Is there anything I could do different or that's easier? 
I know I could use Groupdate-Gem, but there's an issue for date objects and time zone conversion, so I'm trying to do it manually.

EDIT:

The variables @weeklyVoll, @weeklySchon, and @weeklyVegetarisch are for display purposes in my view where the charts are:

```
<%= column_chart [
        { name: "# Bestellungen Vollkost", data: @weeklyVoll },
        { name: "# Bestellungen Schonkost", data: @weeklySchon },
        { name: "# Bestellungen Vegetarisch", data: @weeklyVegetarisch }
        ],
        colors: ["red", "yellow", "green"],
        xtitle: "Wochentag", 
        ytitle: "# Bestellungen",  
        legend: true,
        legend: "bottom",
        messages: { empty: "Noch keine Daten vorhanden!" },
        library: { scales: { yAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: true }, ticks: { precision: 0 } } ] }, animation: {easing: 'easeOutQuad', duration: 2500} }
 %>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What's the value (as an example) of `@weeklyVoll` (or any of others)?.

Comment: I edited my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is having the three different arrays. If you were to group on day/dish_type and then call count at the end it *should* give a results like `['Day', 'Dish Type'] => 3`. You would then have to iterate through and format again as needed. I tend to use `each_with_object`.

```
OrderCard.where(day: Date.today.all_week)
  .group(:day, :dish_type).count
# => ['Day', 'Dish Type'] => 3
```

Comment: Consider using `all_week` which helps you to get rid of the `beginning_of_week` and `end_of_week` range.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I had no idea of that, that's cool! Thanks :D

Comment: Yeah that's a handy note, thanks! Now I Just have to fix the other problem :D

Comment: The problem is that I need 3 different column bars, so I don't think this will work if I group all 3 records together :/

Comment: That's where the each with object comes in. It will allow you to format the data to account for where there is no dish type for a certain day, because it won't be there.